# How to make first row selected in this simple angularjs grid

Tags: angularjs

I am getting response of employee data in

```
$scope.employeeData = response.data;
```

How can make first row as selected by default

```
  <tr ng-repeat="row in employeeData">
                <td>
                    <a ng-click="Test(row)"> {{row.employeeName}}</a>
                </td>
                <td>{{row.employeeStatus}}</td>
                <td>{{row.employeeDesignation}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: when you say selected as default do you mean highlighted? or selected in the angular controller to do something?

Comment: I want to get it selected technically so my `ng-click="Test(row)"` will fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.SelectedRow = response.data[0]


var test  = function(row) {$scope.SelectedRow = row};
```

Just manually select the row in the controller, Then in your controller wire up the selected row as you see fit, or if you want your test to fire you can do something like this

```
test(response.data[0]);

var test = function(row) {$scope.SelectedRow = row;}
```

*******EDIT******

```
app.controller("fooController", ["$scope", "dataService",  function ($scope, dataService) {

$scope.SelectedRow;//the selected row youwant to show
$scope.employeeData; //your data to display

self.test = function(row){ $scope.SelectedRow = row;}

//call your service to get your data

    dataService.GetData().then(function(result){
    $scope.employeeData = response.data;
    test(response.data[0]);//this will fire on "page load" 
    });


    }]);
```

Comment: but this will fire only after `ng-click="Test(row)"` is clicked but I want something on page load and by default first row from grid should be selected and after I select first row I am trying to use that first row on page load.

Comment: You need to post a trimmed down controller then, it sounds like you have more requirements as you discuss this.

Comment: all I need is just to select first row  if exist on page load by default

Comment: There, once you get your data, just call your test, this will "act" just like someone clicking it on load.

Comment: This works as expected. Thanks for answering. Please let me know if you have any other approaches.